# How do you handle associative arrays in CSV imports?

Tags: php, csv, associative-array

I'm building a CSV import where the first row is the column names of everything else.  Instead of having `$row[0]` I'd like to use `$row['id']` to keep the code readable and make it easier for future developers.  The problem is... I can't think of an efficient way to do this...

```
while (($current = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== false) {
    if ($row == 0) {

    }
}
```

The only methods I can think of require a bit of legwork and I'd like to just have a simple solution that's clean and easy (every developers dream, I know).  So I thought I'd post here and see if someone had a better method than what I'm thinking...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind... just found [array_combine](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) on PHP.net... it looks like exactly what I need

```
 <?php
$a = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
$b = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);
?>

Array
(
    [green]  => avocado
    [red]    => apple
    [yellow] => banana
)
```

I'd delete my question but I think this would be useful for some people to know...

Comment: It's perfectly fine to answer your own question.

Comment: ^and encouraged. this site is more about answers to programming questions, than helping any single person with their specific question.